# Properly terminate the selenium browser in Python

Tags: python, linux, selenium, automation, geckodriver

After I finish running the following `Python` code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from contextlib import closing

with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
  # some code here
```

There are still listening geckodriver processes in my `Linux` machine.

```
$ ss -arp
LISTEN      0      128                                                    localhost:44132                                                           *:*        users:(("geckodriver",21698,3))
LISTEN      0      128                                                    localhost:57893                                                           *:*        users:(("geckodriver",20242,3))
LISTEN      0      128                                                    localhost:34439                                                           *:*        users:(("geckodriver",19440,3))
LISTEN      0      128                                                    localhost:35435
```

How to adjust the `Python` code, so that it will terminate the processes as well?

Answer (score 1):

That is because in case of selenium `close` method closes the current window/browser but not exit it. You need to use `quit` method. So your code should be

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def quiting(thing):
    try:
        yield thing
    finally:
        thing.quit()

with quiting(Firefox()) as browser:
    browser.get("http://sample.com")
```